# XSLT Replace tag value by default

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this XML document :

```
<Document>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c1>CCC111</c1>
            <c2>CCCC222</c2>
        </b>
        <d>
            <d1>DDD111</d1>
            <d2>DDD222</d2>
            <d3>DDD333</d3>
        </d>
</a>
</Document>
```

I want to replace the value of Document/a/d/d1 by XXXXXX :

```
<Document>
    <a>
        <b>
            <c1>CCC111</c1>
            <c2>CCCC222</c2>
        </b>
        <d>
            <d1>XXXXXX</d1>
            <d2>DDD222</d2>
            <d3>DDD333</d3>
        </d>
</a>
</Document>
```

I have this XSLT :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Document/a/d/d1/text()">
       XXXXXX
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I obtain the same input and output :/

Thank you.

Comment: You `<Document>` tag is not closed -- opened twice.

Comment: Thank you but this error is just on the post , my XML is valid

Comment: Works for me using xsltproc...  What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you're showing exactly what you have?   It works here with an XSLT 2.0 processor -- Saxon HE (SaxonHE9-5-1-2J) -- and an XSLT 1.0 processor -- Saxon 6.5.5.

Comment: Okay it run when a have <Document> but in my input file i have : <Document xmlns="tatatta" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="totoot">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that there's a simple transcription mistake somewhere along the line.  While you might simplify your `XXXXXX` override template a bit:

```
<xsl:template match="d1/text()">XXXXXX</xsl:template>
```

what you've posted works as-is and illustrates that you have the concepts down right.  I can confirm that what you've posted works with XSLT 2.0 (Saxon HE) and XSLT 1.0 (Saxon 6.5.5) processors.

**Update after discovery of namespace definition:**

Ok, so the elements of the input XML document are in a namespace.  No problem, just declare a namespace prefix for the `tatatta` namespace and adjust the  `template/@match` to account for the namespace like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:t="tatatta">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="t:d1/text()">XXXXXX</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Okay it run when a have <Document> but in my input file i have : <Document xmlns="tatatta" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:schemaLocation="totoot">

Comment: @l4r3nZu, ah, that explains it!  No problem.  Answer updated above to account for the the namespace.

Comment: Thank it work fine :) I have possible join the value of <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:t="tatatta"> and the value of my XML : <Document xmlns="tatatta" ???

Answer (score 2):

> in my input file i have : `<Document xmlns="tatatta" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="totoot">`

This means that the elements in your document are in the `tatatta` namespace, and since unprefixed names in XPath 1.0 always refer to non-namespaced elements your template won't match.  You need to map the namespace to a prefix and use that in the pattern, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="t:Document/t:a/t:d/t:d1/text()"
              xmlns:t="tatatta">
  <xsl:text>XXXXXX</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

(or you could put the `xmlns:t` on your `xsl:stylesheet` instead of on the template, if you need to use the same namespace in other places).

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Document/a/d/d1/text()[.='DDD111']">XXXXXX </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```